# Install tweepy on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, tweepy

So I followed the directions on the website to install tweepy with:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

Only modification I had to do was `sudo python3 setup.py install` for permission reasons and to install for python 3.4

I keep getting the error:

> six 1.5.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/six-1.5.2-py3.4.egg
>   error: Could not find required distribution six>=1.7.3

However if I type:

```
$ pip freeze | grep six
six==1.9.0. 
$ pip freeze | grep tweepy
tweepy==3.3.0
```

If I go to simply import tweepy on the my machine I get `ImportError: No module names 'requests_oauthlib'`. What step am I missing?

The install worked fine on my windows computer, but on my Ubuntu computer (not VM) I'm getting these errors.

Comment: are you sure you're using pip3 as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I found out, in my case since tweepy was installed under python 3.4 but somehow the oauthlib was not,  I ran `$ sudo python3 -m pip install requests requests_oauthlib` which fixed the error and I was able to import tweepy without error.

It is possible that pip3 could have done it originally without errors as deathangel908 said, but I didn't test it since the previous line fixed the issue.

**For general purpose:**

Python 3.x

```
sudo pip3 install tweepy
```

Python 2.x

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```